# MSE Help dropdown still links back to SO

Tags: bug, mso-mse-split

A minor point to be sure, but the help drop-down still points to Stack Overflow as the main site.

[image: eeeeeek]

It should probably point to https://stackexchange.com/.

Comment: Yep, it's a dupe.